# Hilla Vaadin Router and optional named parameter with regexp pattern

Tags: typescript, routes, vaadin, hilla, path-to-regexp

I am using Vaadin Hilla and like to define a route in my typescript frontend `routes.ts` with an optional named parameter for the language which should be optional like `:lang?`. The optional language parameter should follow a reg-exp pattern for two alphabetical character `\w{2}`.

So the route should match:

- /categoryA/categortyB/...
- /en/categoryA/categoryB/...
- /de/categoryA/categoryB/...

I tried multiple multiple variants for the path, but I could not make the named parameter `:lang` optional when I use a regexp pattern like `:lang(\\w{2})?` or `:lang(\\w{2}?)` or  `:lang((\\w{2})?)`. The only thing which seems to work is `:lang?`

Any suggestions?

```
import type { Commands, Context, Route } from '@vaadin/router';
...
export const routes: Route[] = [
   {
    path: '/:lang(\\w{2})?/:cat*',
    component: 'route-test-view',
    action: async (_context, _command) => {
      await import('./views/route-test-view');
      return;
    },
}
];
...
```

- Link to [Hilla Route documentation](https://hilla.dev/docs/lit/guides/routing#parameters)
- Link to [Path-To-Regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#modifiers)